# Can you buy a ticket from the home side but sit in the away section?

Tags: football, english-premier-league

I would like to watch a game between a local club where I am currently attending university and the club I support. Can I buy a match ticket from the home side but sit in the away section and support the visiting club?

Comment: No, in normal, the tickets for the away section(s) are sold by the away team. The get a fixed contingent from the home team to sell. If there're tickets left, they go back to the home team, and they will decide if would be ok (for security reasons) to sell them to (neutral) supporters.
You can try to buy the ticket from the away side, but in nearly all cases I know, they sell these tickets only to club members, or season ticket holders.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info? Where, what game,...? But in most cases: no.

Comment: Just buy a home ticket and keep your mouth shut when the away team score. The occasional *sigh* whenever the home team loses the ball should help to maintain your cover

Comment: Maybe this works differently at your place, but at the stadia that I have been to, your seat number is mentioned on your ticket, and the guards won't let you in to a different section. You could, of course, exchange your ticket with another spectator, but good luck doing that with someone from another section, especially when there is this home/away separation involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, you cannot do this.

There are rare occasions when it *does* happen.  For instance, a finals match at a home stadium. A good example of this is UEFA 2012 Finals.

Comment: Why?  Do you have any citations for this?

Comment: So many reasons

Comment: @scriptHero Mostly to do with fan separation. There may be some exceptions, for example Fulham have special FA dispensation to have a neutral area, where home and away fans can mingle.